# $u \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega) \Rightarrow |u| \in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$

Tags: functional-analysis, sobolev-spaces

For $\epsilon>0 $ define $g_\epsilon(u)=\sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2}-\epsilon$.

One finds $ \nabla g_\epsilon(u)=\frac{u}{\sqrt{\epsilon^2+u^2}}\nabla u$
and $ g_\epsilon(u)\in W_0^{1,2}(\Omega)$ .

Then it holds $\int_{\Omega}|\nabla g_\epsilon(u)|^2dx \leq \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2dx$

For some sequence ${n_k} \subset \mathbb{N}$ it follows

$\int_{\Omega}|\nabla |u||^2dx=\int_{\Omega}\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}|\nabla g_\frac{1}{n_k}(u)|^2 dx=\lim\limits_{k \rightarrow \infty}\int_{\Omega}|\nabla g_\frac{1}{n_k}(u)|^2 dx \leq \int_{\Omega}|\nabla u|^2dx $ (1)

I do not really understand what (1) says .

Comment: At the end, $\int_\Omega  |\nabla |u||^2\leq \int_\Omega |\nabla u|^2<\infty ,$ and thus $|u|\in W^{1,2}$.

Comment: but why is  $|u| \in L^2$ ?

Comment: and why does it follow that $|u| \in W_0^{1,2}$?

Comment: 1) $u\in L^2\iff |u|\in L^2$. 2)  $u|_{\partial \Omega }(x)=0\iff |u||_{\partial \Omega }(x)=0$

Comment: I think that is the definition with the trace

Comment: $W_0^{1,2} $ is the closure of $C_c^{\infty}$ or is it equivalent ?

Comment: $W_0^{1,2}$ is the closure of $\mathcal C_c^\infty $ and it's equal to the set $\{f\in W^{1,2}\mid Trace(f)=0\}$

Comment: thanks for your answer . Well , then it also holds that $ Trace(g\epsilon(u))=0$

Comment: Can one proof it also without using traces ?

Comment: Can I take $g_{\frac{1}{n}(u)}$ as Cauchy sequence in $W^{1,2}$?